# $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ of $(-1)^{n}$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ of the sequence $a_{n}=(-1)^{n}$. I did the following:

By definition: $\lim \sup(a_{n})=\inf\left\{\sup\left\{a_{m}:m\geq n\right\}:n \geq 0\right\}$. Analogous definition for $\lim \inf$.

I have that $\lim \sup(a_{n})=1$ and $\lim \inf(a_{n})=-1$

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusions for their values are correct.

To show it formally, start by noting/showing that $\{a_m : m \geq n\} = \{-1, 1\}$ for every $n$.  The results follow almost immediately from this.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed $x_{n}$ for $a_{n}$